# .FormulaR1C1 containing variables with values read from files

Tags: excel, variables, vba

The code lines

> ```
> .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R1C1="&Chr(34)&text&Chr(34)&",1,0)"
>
> .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-3]C[2]="&Chr(34)&text&Chr(34)&",1,0)"
> ```

are examples of the usual manner to insert R1C1 formulas in target cells when the addresses of the target cells are already known. No problem with that.

BUT...I can't find the way to devise a general R1C1 formula that can be used to do the job when the addresses of the target cells aren't previously known, but they are read from different text files instead, and both, rows and columns, may vary from one occasion to the next, getting inserted by means of loops. The following code lines can give an idea of what I'd like to have in a text file to be read, inserted in a cell and work properly:

> ```
>  "=IF(R[-"&varRow&"]C["&varCol&"]="&Chr(34)&text&Chr(34)&",1,0)"
>
>  "=IF(R"&varRow&"C"&varCol&"="&Chr(34)&text&Chr(34)&",1,0)"
> ```

In other words, I can't figure out how to use variables for the numbers of rows and columns in the examples given above. I asume such a possibility exists, but I have ran out of ideas on how to implement it. I've implemented some, but I've just gotten the code to be inserted as the value for the cells or the #NOMBRE(#NAME) error.

What is a solution to this problem?

Comment: You seem to be on the right lines. Sometimes helps to assign your formula string to a variable and print it to the immediate window or to a cell where any errors may become apparent. In fact your code works for m, allowing for @ScottCraner's comments. Just get some spaces between your &s.

Comment: I assume that both the varRow and varCol are Longs and that the varRow, since it is negative is not greater than or equal to the row in which your are putting the formula?

Comment: Wow! That's what I call "speedy". Thanks, SJR and Scott.You are right, but I totally forgot a "very" important detail that could be the cause of all my trouble: the R1C1 formula is to be written in the text file and be read from it too; so, how does it have to be written in the text file?.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to "replay" your issue...or I understood it wrong.

If I use this code:

```
Range("C2").Select
Dim varRow As String
Dim varCol As String
varCol = 2
varRow = 2
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[" & varRow & "]C[" & varCol & "]=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",1,0)"
```

The right formula appears in cell A1 and does its job.

To write this in a file, just put the formula string as it is in a string variable and write it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rafa.

Comment: Sorry, Rafa. I'll check what you posted and will report the result. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Rafa. I got to the solution and posted it. You may read it.

Answer (score 0):

Scott, SJR, and anyone reading this post.

Apologies in advance for the length of this post, but I think that the matter deserves it.

I have managed to solve the situation regarding the FormulaR1C1 format when it is to be loaded from a text file. However, I'm not totally sure of the why and the how involved in the analysis and the solution. Maybe you can give a thorough explanation about it.

The fact is that the solution (formula format) you have given, quite similar to the one given by Microsoft and similar to the result obtained when recording the macro in entering the procedure by hand, when entered as plain text in a text file and then read from it and placed in a cell just doesn't give the result expected. An example of the original data in a text file:

```
22_2_|"=IF(R[" & varRow & "]C[" & varCol & "]=" & Chr(34) & varValue & Chr(34) & ",1,0)"
```

"22" would be the row number (varRow) and "2" the column number (varCol).

I tried every different logical possibility that came to my mind over and over, all of them with similar results: failure. Then I decided to forget logic and try random thoughts.

First thing I did on this new trail was to revise the original idea: use a general formula exclusively with variables in it. I realized that I was making a stupid mistake giving the value for the variable -for instance, the column and row number- and right next to it placing the variable in the formula at the same time. Why to do it that way? Why not to place the numbers for the row and column directly in the formula? After all, the formula should work the same all the way.

An example for this new approach could be:

```
"=IF(R[number]C[number]=" & Chr(34) & varValue & Chr(34) & ",1,0)"
```

I did it this way and tested it, with dissapointing results, similar to the ones obtained at first.

Then I thought about the quotes used for the formula format. Could it be possible that the reason for the problem might have to do with them? Well, there was only one way to find out. So I tried it this way, then this other way, an other..and other...and then...EUREKA!...This is what I got, that finally works:

```
=IF(R22C2="value",1,0)
```

As you may notice, the final formula ends up having no variables at all. That was a stupid idea on my side, considering that the data is going to be obtained from a text file. So, forget the variables. BUT...and this is a very important "BUT"...

Notice what has happened to the quotes. The only ones remaning are the ones that enclose the value that is to be compared. All the others have dissapeared. And this is the only way in which the formula, when read from the text file and inserted in a cell, ends up as a functional formula in the cell, and not as the value for the cell or as a "#NAME?" error. And now, a very important question: WHY? My answer for it: I have no idea.

I must suppose -and that's the most I can do at this moment- that the fact the formula is being read from a text file and inserted as text in the cell is handled by Excel in a "certain way" that already includes -behind curtains- the necessary quotes in the internal works of the worksheet. So, if you previously include some quotes, the formula ends up having an excess of them and the final product is not the one expected. Might that be it? Who can tell? Well, what matters to me is that, as strange as it may look, it now works as I wanted it. Give it a try yourself, and then tell me.

Well, pals, that's it. And thanks a lot to all for your kind and timely help.